# ctypes python create string structure

Tags: python, ctypes, d

I have a struct like below in dlang

```
struct gph
{
    string x;
    string y;

}
```

and a function as follows:

```
pragma(mangle, "print_gph")
void print_gph(gph g)
{
    stderr.writeln(g.x);
   
}
```

I have created a .so file and trying to access it from Python. I have created a Ctype for the same in Python

```
class gph(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x_p', c_char_p),
        ('x_len', c_size_t),

        ('y_p', c_char_p),
        ('y_len', c_size_t),
    ]

_input = create_string_buffer(b"input 1")
sample_struct = gph()
sample_struct.x_p = cast(_input, c_char_p) 
sample_struct.x_len = c_size_t(sizeof(_input))

lib.print_gph(c_void_p(),
       sample_struct) //calling Dlang function
```

however i am getting some error like below

```
src/rt/dwarfeh.d:330: uncaught exception reached top of stack
This might happen if you're missing a top level catch in your fiber or signal handler
std.exception.ErrnoException@/usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/stdio.d(3170): Enforcement failed (Bad address)
Aborted
```

I am suspecting that the `char_p` assignment or the structure creation is not correct.  i have to pass `c_void_p()` as my `gph` function is within a `struct`. (meaning it is point to `this` or `self`)

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with C than D, but you should only need to pass the initialized structure.  You only need `create_string_buffer` if the string needs to be writable.  a read-only string can use the Python `bytes` type.

```py
import ctypes as ct

class gph(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (('x_p', ct.c_char_p),
                ('x_len', ct.c_size_t),
                ('y_p', ct.c_char_p),
                ('y_len', ct.c_size_t))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x_p = x
        self.x_len = len(x)
        self.y_p = y
        self.y_len = len(y)

lib = ct.CDLL('./test')
lib.print_gph.argtypes = ct.POINTER(gph),
lib.print_gph.restype = None

g = gph(b'hello', b'world')
lib.print_gph(g)
```